# Update column value by 1 in Oracle table conditionally

Tags: sql, database, oracle

I have an Oracle table with 4 columns `(Name, Phone, Email, Count)`.

If the user is updating value of `Name` column, then I need to increment `Count` column value by 1.

If the user is updating values other than `Name` column, then I don't need to increment `Count` column value by 1.

Initially, when the record is inserted, `Count` should be 0. And every time when `Name` column is updated, the `Count` should be incremented by 1 (like 1, 2, 3 .....).

How we can achieve this? I am very new to databases.

Thanks a lot for your help.

Answer (score 13):

You can do that in an update and insert trigger or in your program. The later however requires all possible programs to cooperate. The former (triggers) is black art.

A program can do it like this:

```
UPDATE Person SET Count=Count+1, Phone='123' WHERE name=`csr` and Phone <> '123';
```

This will update one or no record (i.e. if phone was already 123 it will do nothing).

BTW: there is no nice solution to insert it if it was missing.

Hmm, you changed your question, updating the Name is problematic if you do not have another primary key, is that really what you want?

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking at plsql procedure, then you can use this method,
I am using 3 input variables,

1.) column name to edit

2.) old value

3.) New value to be updated

```
SQL>   create or replace procedure updateval (colname varchar2,oldval varchar2,newval varchar2) is
  2    l_prop varchar2(10);
  3    l_newval varchar2(10);
  4    l_old_val varchar2(10);
  5       begin
  6      l_prop:=colname;
  7      l_newval:=newval;
  8      l_old_val:=oldval;
  9       IF (upper(l_prop)='NAME') THEN
 10       update TESTING123 set  name=l_newval,count=count+1 where name=l_old_val;
 11       elsif (upper(l_prop)='PHONE') THEN
 12       update TESTING123 set  PHONE=l_newval ,count=count+1where PHONE=l_old_val;
 13       elsif (upper(l_prop)='EMAIL') THEN
 14       update TESTING123 set  EMAIL=l_newval ,count=count+1 where EMAIL=l_old_val;
 15        END IF;
 16    end;
 17   /

Procedure created.


SQL>
SQL> select * from testing123;

NAME       PHONE      EMAIL           COUNT
---------- ---------- ---------- ----------
abc1       12345      ABC@a.COM           1
xyz        3435       xyz@a.COM           0


SQL> exec updateval ('NAME','abc1','newabc1');

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.


SQL>
SQL>
SQL> select * from testing123;

NAME       PHONE      EMAIL           COUNT
---------- ---------- ---------- ----------
newabc1    12345      ABC@a.COM           2
xyz        3435       xyz@a.COM           0
```